# Xcode change naming of files and folders to be approval ready

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, rename, appstore-approval

I want to submit my app to the apple approval process. According to the guideline, they will reject apps that are beta versions.

During the history of development, my code was based on an earlier beta version, thats why I have some files and folders, which contains the string "beta":

```
./FooBeta 
./FooBeta/FooBeta-Info.plist 
./FooBeta/FooBeta-Prefix.pch 
./FooBeta.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/bar.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/FooBeta.xcscheme 
./FooBeta.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/FooBeta.xccheckout 
./FooBetaTests/FooBetaTests-Info.plist 
./FooBetaTests/FooBetaTests.m
```

I want know to remove the beta string. **How to I do this best, while not harm my app?**

I am a little bit concerned with the files: Info-Plist, Prefix.pch, xuserdata, xcsahreddata, that changing them lead to unexpecting errors, as the files cannot be found...

Besides the files, I have to rename the bundle identifier, bundle display name and bundle name. (the last I am not sure)

Do you have any tips or hints what I have (more) to consider?

Comment: tip: don't use the word "beta" in the app name at all.  Other than the bundle name, I doubt Apple will even notice the other names.

Comment: Ok. @trojanfoe not sure if I translate/understand that correct: "Other then the bundle name" means, as well to change the bundle name? I figured as well out that I have to change the *bundle **display** name*, that the name appears correctly on the app icon. the bundle name has now effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Apple say they will reject beta version apps, they mean just that. Not that it contains a string "beta".

Think about it logically - what if I created a Greek alphabet app… Alpha, Beta, Gamma, etc

Or just an alphabetapp (alpha-beta-pp, geddit?)

Just make sure you don't use any description in your app's name or UI or your iTunesConnect submission that says it's a beta version.

Comment: I would add: as long as you don't have the word Beta alone, you may pass the review process (I mean, there would be no problem with FooBeta). Anyway, it could be problematic having the name in the App Name, title, bundle, etc. I have seen an app being rejected by having a small "beta" in the icon, nothing else. You never know with Apple... This is just my thoughts in a comment.